# Binomial Option Pricing Model gives increasingly higher value for out-of-the-money options

Tags: option-pricing, binomial-tree

I was developing the binomial option pricing model via Python, according to the explanation given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model). After computing the errors against the pricing of real options, I find an interesting observation: for ITM or ATM options, the pricing is valid with an absolute error of < 5%. Options have increasing errors the further they are out of the money.

Can someone please verify that this is true? I want to make sure that my model is accurate.

Is there any reason that the binomial option pricing model is not well suited for OTM options?

Here is a sample data I collected with SPY calls for March 31st, 2021. The current SPY price (as of March 5th, 2021 Close) is 383.86.

```
'''
dictionary legend: {strike price: error}
error = (calculated value - actual value) / actual value
'''
{365.0: -0.10398725960867114, 
366.0: 0.03886695456098042, 
367.0: 0.015123243825304564, 
368.0: -0.056625598046850474, 
369.0: 0.04160187776458406, 
370.0: -0.0574508046179877, 
371.0: 0.015879270136192072, 
372.0: -0.05635870165502236, 
373.0: 0.03225622009989104, 
374.0: -0.08397890047776085, 
375.0: -0.07962166687395124, 
376.0: -0.0969464667647878, 
377.0: -0.08587962526643103, 
378.0: -0.06138202808017936, 
379.0: -0.10073723690291991, 
380.0: -0.061071922706695654, 
381.0: -0.0559249614427142, 
382.0: -0.02482521293918986, 
383.0: -0.04269612722165317, << at the money
384.0: -0.04943243855493896, << at the money
385.0: 0.007619264189264405, << error ramps up
386.0: 0.03472779315930944, 
387.0: 0.06471821606406522, 
388.0: 0.09511872979332835, 
389.0: 0.13398417397216475, 
390.0: 0.17659937956617186, 
391.0: 0.2179829015094537, 
392.0: 0.28442013677060846, 
393.0: 0.2661790269442991, 
394.0: 0.3549817896985142, 
395.0: 0.48815688050452904, 
396.0: 0.552946217531983, 
397.0: 0.5818511876956546, 
398.0: 1.0168585946008368, 
399.0: 0.9562900531249798, 
400.0: 0.8933095809737509, 
401.0: 1.030261932540089, 
402.0: 1.079947643164871}
```

Below is the graph of the errors.
[image: Error Graph]

Comment: Are those options European? I am assuming so. OTM options should be more liquid than at the money options. But perhaps it is your binomial model that is not correct. What if the world is different i.e. what if you do not live in a Black-Scholes world? As in what if the interest rate is stochastic or the volatility is stochastic?

Comment: Also, what are the errors in percentage or the actual price?

Comment: @phdstudent Thank you for your reply. This is American option, so there is max(exercise value, binomial value) at each step of the calculation. I agree that the interest rate is stochastic and may cause inaccuracies. I use the most recent 10-year treasury bond as the interest rate, although it changes over time. Nevertheless, it is highly probable that I am missing something from the binomial model. I just couldn't find it yet.

Comment: I am not sure if using the same volatility (around 0.18) causes the spike in OTM, although there is no indication that it does the same for ITM options (I haven't tested deep ITM options). I will see what happens when I change the volatility.